# Updating Expression Parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here's my code:

```
public static Response<TResult> Create<TResult>(Expression<Func<Response<TResult>>> method)
{
    var objectMember = Expression.Convert(((MethodCallExpression)method.Body).Arguments[0], typeof(TResult));
    var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult>>(objectMember);
    var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
    TResult myObject = getter();

    // Do something to 'myObject'

    // Call original method with updated 'myObject' as the parameter
}
```

As you can see from the code snippet above, I have a generic method that accepts a method as a parameter.

Orginally, I was calling  `method.Compile()()` which worked fine.  However, I now need to update the parameter ("myObject") first before calling the method.  So, I've added the lines above to get the parameter.

I then "Do something to 'myObject'".  Finally, I want to call the original passed method, but replace the original parameter with the new, updated parameter.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

So, I've, *technically*, accomplished my need by the following code:

```
Response<TResult> result = (Response<TResult>)((MethodCallExpression)method.Body).Method.Invoke(parentType, new object[] { myObject });
```

But this is using a lot of reflection and casting.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Joshua

Comment: What is the method supposed to be doing? What sort of expressions are you calling this with? It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: sample code that would call this method is `Response<MyType> response = Data.DataHelper.Create<MyType>(() => _repo.InsertType(myType));`  So the method above, would update `myType` before inserting it into the repository.

Comment: Where does the argument come from given the expression passed in is for a delegate of a no-argument function?